# Add ID to listener after loading remote image

Tags: lua, listener, coronasdk

I have a listener for loading remote images, but I need to be able to pass an ID number to that listener, and I'm not really sure how to do it. My code to retrieve the remote image is:

```
display.loadRemoteImage("http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg", "GET", networkListener, "banner.png",system.TemporaryDirectory,  (globalData.contentX * rows2) + globalData.contentX/2, 20 + (i - 1) % 6 * 140
```

And the listener I have is:

```
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print ( "Network error - download failed" )
    else
        local target = event.target
        target.alpha = 0
        transition.to( target, { alpha = 1.0 } )
        target.width = 590
        target.height = 110 
        target:addEventListener( "touch", target )
        scrollView:insert(target) 
        function target:touch(event)
            if event.phase == "began" then
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( self )
                self.isFocus = true

            elseif self.isFocus then
                if event.phase == "moved" then
                    numMoved = numMoved + 1
                    if(numMoved > 10) then
                        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                        self.isFocus = false
                        scrollView:takeFocus( event )
                    end
                elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
                    globalData.selectedLocationID = target.id --This needs to be the ID that I pass to this listener
                    if(globalData.approvedToggle == 1) then
                        storyboard.gotoScene("businessScene")
                    else
                        storyboard.gotoScene("locationScene")
                    end
                    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                    self.isFocus = false
                end
            end
        return true
    end
end
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back on an Ecommerence app I was making. I'm not to familer with storyboard, but I do remember using this API.  If I remember correctly, you need to use event.target as the event listener and pass everything through there.  I also remember that you can embed a function inside of the display.loadRemoteImage API like this:

```
itemImage = display.loadRemoteImage(itemData.imageURL, "GET", 
            function(event)
               event.target.xScale = 0.4
               event.target.yScale = 0.4
               function openSite(event)
                   if event.phase == "ended" then
                      system.openURL( itemData.itemURL )
                   end
               end 
               event.target:addEventListener( "tap", openSite )
            end)
```

My advice is remove all the story board stuff, and try making the API work in a different document.  I think that you need to simplify it so you aren't confused.

Hopefully this helps.